# How to do parameterization for file name text of csv data set config in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am passing the value for file name text filed in csv data set config as ${filename}, this variable contains entire path and fetching it form one more csv data set config which is present immediate to the thread group and the variable which I am passing to csv data set config that is inside the if controller here I couldn't able to pass that value to file name text filed, getting problem.

Comment: Do you mean to say that, you have a *CSV file* which contains the *file path & file names* of one or more *CSV files* which you are passing into another *CSV Data set Config* using *${filename}*. please clarify?

Comment: Yes,i have multiple file names and its path in the csv file,i am reading those file names by using csv data set config using variable name as 'filename' and in the if controller i have one more csv data set config to read the content of each file here dat variable reffering as ${filename} for file name text field of csv data set config but the variable is not replacing with value.

Answer (score 5):

CSV Data Set Config cannot use JMeter Variable as the "Filename". However it is possible to use [__property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function there.

So your test plan should look as follows:

1. Read some value into a JMeter Variable i.e. `foo` via 1st CSV Data Set Config
2. Convert `foo` variable into `foo` property via [__setProperty](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function
3. Use `${__property(foo,,)}` as a "Filename" in 2nd CSV Data Set Config.

For more information on different JMeter's functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series

Comment: I have the test plan like this in my script                         Testplan                                                            ThreadGroup                                                          CSVdataSetConifg(from here i am reading allthe filpath by using variable name as 'filename')                                        BeanshellSampler                                                   If controller                                                       Csv Data Set config(here i am refering that variable as ${filename} in FileName Text field)

Comment: *CSV Data Set Config cannot use JMeter Variable as the "Filename"* Is this by design?

Comment: I'm not JMeter developer hence I know only that CSV Data Set config is initialized **before** variables initialization. And JMeter Properties are usual Java Properties which initialized on JVM start and live until JVM destruction. Probably it is by design.