# Parametrize source folder directory or file path in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, parameterization

Is there any way to parameterize the CSV data file path or source directory path in JMeter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do parameterization for file name text of csv data set config in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721871/how-to-do-parameterization-for-file-name-text-of-csv-data-set-config-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 possibilities:

1. Via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) like:

   [image]

   and then referring the variable in the CSV Data Set Config

   [image]
2. Or via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   [image]

   the property value can be passed via `-J` command line argument or put into the *user.properties* file. See [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) for more information.